# Take away the EXISTS but leave in the switch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I modify the final script to also have an exclusions switch? I do not want to use `EXISTS` in the final script:

```
SELECT MyField = 'x' INTO #Data
UNION SELECT MyField = 'y'
UNION SELECT MyField = 'z'
UNION SELECT MyField = 'j'
UNION SELECT MyField = 'q'
UNION SELECT MyField = NULL;

SELECT MyField = 'j' INTO #Exclusions
UNION  SELECT MyField = 'q'
UNION SELECT MyField = NULL;


DECLARE @ShowAll TINYINT = 1; -->>exceptions "switch" is turned ON so all data returned
SELECT *
FROM   #Data d
WHERE  @ShowAll = 1 OR 
       (
       EXISTS
         (
         SELECT d.MyField 
         EXCEPT
         SELECT MyField FROM #Exclusions
         )
       );

--can I simplify and get rid of the EXISTS but still include a switch based on @ShowAll ? 
SELECT *
FROM   #Data d
       EXCEPT
       SELECT MyField FROM #Exclusions;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   #Data d
       EXCEPT
       SELECT MyField FROM #Exclusions WHERE @ShowAll <> 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3125

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this in a stored procedure and pass the switch as an option.

Comment: it _already is_ wrapped in a stored procedure and either 1 or 0 is being passed in ...that's the point of the question: how do I implement this query so that the script can interpret the 1 or 0 as either inclusions or exclusions